# Same Sencha app for web and mobile

Tags: java, extjs

Query is : I have a current web application in place to provide me data in a list which is built using java and ui is built using jsp. I want to design a mobile app in Sencha to perform the same task and simultaneously want it in desktop using Sencha/ExtJs.

Now I am confused in following manner :

1. Do I need to create separate applications for web app and mobile app?
2. For the web app I need to load a separate set of files whereas for the mobile app it is different. If the application is one then can I do this?
3. Also, all the java files which I am using for the getting the list data, should be in same code base or separate?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencha is a mobile app development framework based on HTML5 and query. So the controls and views are basically designed for mobile screens. But it does not stop you to display the same content on normal desktop browsers. Although what looks great on mobile may not look that good on a browser and vice versa.

> Do I need to create separate applications for web app and mobile app?

Not really, everything can be same, views middleware and even backend. If you can design a UI that may look both on mobile and desktop then you are good.

> For the web app I need to load a separate set of files whereas for the
>   mobile app it is different. If the application is one then can I do
>   this?

As I said above, except UI nothing should be a concern. If you want different look and feel for web and mobile then just create different HTML files for the said purposes. But you can use the same backend logic.

> Also, all the java files which I am using for the getting the list
>   data, should be in same code base or separate?

Generally dynamic web applications fetches the data from backend servers using ajax/http service calls. You may manage the code in a single project or can divide it in logically smaller projects for better management. Maven should be a good choice to manage your projects.

Comment: Thanks Juned. I have one question as my web app need to get opened on mobile browsers also. So I need a code base where if it is desktop I need to fetch the views from desktop folder which will be using ext js where as in case of mobile browser it should fetch from sencha touch folder which will have views implemented using sencha touch. Is this possible? If yes then what check I can put to load these views and where?

Comment: Just put them in different folders so that your fetch URLs look like these : yourhost:port/yourwebapp/mobile/welcome.html .... yourhost:port/yourwebapp/web/welcome.html